# Handling questions asking for bad practices and the following answers

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

**Scenario**

It seem like a pretty common scenario when OP ask a question of a type

*"How do you I achieve this certain result using a very bad/ frowned upon practice"*

It usually gets a response in comments of type

*"Why use this very bad/ frowned upon practice, just do this simple/efficient solution"*

OPs response

*"Yeah, I know I can achieve it this way, but I insist on the very bad/ frowned upon practice because [it is more readable/fits my code better/etc.]"*

What usually happens next, is 5-10 newly registered users post ridiculously awful answers that fit the description of the question and actually meet the OP's *"standards"*.

---

**Use Case**

[Here's a recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887815/r-loop-data-frame-and-extract-subset-of-rows-and-columns) (let's try avoiding Meta effects for once, shall we?)

I'm not going to talk in too much detail regarding what's so wrong in OP's preferred practice as most of you haven't even heard of R, but one could solve the question using a one-liner such as `df[10:15, c('a','d')]` which is how it should be solved according to any R tutorial I'm aware of. Now look at the proposed answers there.

---

**Possible solutions**

Now my doubts are:

1. Put the question on hold until OP specifies a good enough reason regarding the why they are looking for such a solution
2. Downvote or not the answers which are both terrible (well, most of them) but actually answer the question
3. Leave it as is and not to force OP/Answers to follow the commonly accepted practices and mind my own business

---

**My current solution**

Is comment > Close Vote > don't downvote neither the question or the answers (though I feel like they can be very harmful for future readers).

Thoughts?

---

**Update:** Two of the answers have been deleted by the community since this was posted, but this is not so relevant to the question itself.

Comment: I tend to close these as "unclear". Special requirements need to be stated in the Q itself.

Comment: Why not answer it using best practices but with a comment that the OP's required method is not recommended (give reasons). Then your answer is helpful to ***future*** users, if not the OP.

Comment: @Paulie_D mostly because 1 - this could be probably closed as a dupe (if OP wouldn't have requested for a specific practice). 2- I wasn't the one that came up with the solution in comments. 3- this doesn't really answer the question which asks for loops in particular.

Comment: I though you were asking *generally* not about the linked question specifically.

Comment: This is what more or less happens in general (except point #2).

Comment: [Downvote all the things](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YaeH4.jpg)

Comment: Unless the reason for the bad approach is _really well justified_, I'm in the downvote and comment camp. Given that at least 90% of the gratuitous loops in R questions also lack an MCVE, though, a CV is frequently in order, too. The example question is unusually well-structured for one of these, really.

Comment: Arbitrary stupid constraints along the line of "I know I could do this, but I have to do that" are a hallmark of homework questions with a stupid teacher (at least according to my prejudices). That doesn't necessarily say anything about the quality of the post, I just like to be grumpy about this.

Comment: Why not ask why OP wants it this way (maybe it is an assignment and the teacher wants it to be done in a certain way). Maybe there should be a flair/tag to indicate the inquiry is about a sub-optimal solution for future reference.

Comment: @Ytrog We did ask the OP why they want it this way.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I meant as a more general way of handling this.

Comment: @Ytrog yeah, a comment is one of the steps under **My current solution**

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeah I saw a similar case on meta.codereview where one user's teacher forced them to use `using namespace std;` in all C++ programs

Comment: Oh no the question is deleted.

Answer (score 49):

You are welcome to downvote if you think the question doesn't show enough research effort or is generally not useful.

You should **not** put the question on hold unless it fits one of the close reasons. See this extremely good writeup of that point: [A Close Vote is not a Super Downvote](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2115/17772)

As far as the thrust of your question, however...

I have been in the OP's position before. Sometimes, to make the question answerable, I have to dumb down the scenario. In the dumbed down scenario, there's an obvious approach that is infinitely better, but in my much more complicated real-world scenario, the obvious approach simply won't work.

I don't know R well enough to address the question you've referenced, but I do know that in general you should give broad deference to the OP's specific needs, unless you want extremely long, detailed posts that go through months of project history to explain the current system and why the "obvious" solution isn't the right one. Which basically amounts to code review. Which is off-topic.

By all means, question the "bad" approach (if they've not addressed that already), but if they insist that they need the approach requested, I wouldn't get obnoxious about it... real-world programming can be very messy sometimes, and tradeoffs is the name of the game.

Comment: *"In the dumbed down scenario, there's an obvious approach that is infinitely better, but in my much more complicated real-world scenario, the obvious approach simply won't work."* My problem with that reasoning is it is very likely to be an X/Y problem. Sure, there's probably edge cases, like this is homework and teacher says do it this way, but majority of times the problem is Y.

Comment: It's pretty amazing how often I've been forced to follow some anti-pattern because of a design decision made by someone else. Like the PM who insisted on de-normalized databases because "they're easier", or the manager who refused to use foreign keys because "they're slower". True stories.

Comment: The approach proposed in the question is slower than the "correct approach" by several orders of magnitude. Code like this (which seems to be an approach coming naturally to beginners who have some basic knowledge of other, compiled languages) is one reason why people claim R is slow. And that's the reason why experienced R users would prefer not to see answers promoting these approaches. If someone can't code a simple approach which however is completely against the design of the language, should we really show them how to do that?

Comment: I think that the "minimal" in MCVE should not be so minimal as to imply a different solution to the same problem. Or at least in these cases OP can (and should) clearly explain that they're aware of the proper way of doing it, but they have a very good reason why they can't do it (and then specifying the reason).

Comment: @andras based on David's question, the OP has already said this ("*Yeah, I know I can achieve it this way, but I insist on the very bad/ frowned upon practice because*"), but I agree that it's better to have it in the original question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Another IRL example: System should auto-save changes when exiting the page. Bam, synchronous AJAX.

Comment: The main reason I was thinking to put it on hold is because bad content keep piling up which will need to be handled later. I'm not sure if protecting the question could be better. Although many times users with more than 10 rep being irresponsible too.

Answer (score 31):

As a fellow R tag follower, I am sympathetic to the situation. In the case of the specific question that precipitated the discussion, I would downvote, comment, and move on. The requested approach is tragically ill-advised. There is little learning benefit from the approach. It encourages useless coding that is at odds with the R language.

---

With respect to general guidelines, my thinking process takes into account both the OP's question, expected output, and time constraints on my part.

- **Best**:
  Answer both ways. Provide a solution that reflects both the OP's request AND recommended method. OP gets the answer they are looking for. I get to help the user and future intrepid programmers with the "right" way.
  But I make sure that these conditions are met:

  1. The question is clear.
  2. "Bad" method is merely inefficient and not tragically misguided.
  3. "Best" method does not require advanced skill in either understanding or applying the solution.
  4. Time constraints do not prohibit writing up both answers.
- **Better**:
  Answer one method with warning on the other. Provide either OP's method or "best" method with an applicable warning on tangential options. The constraints for this course of action would include the first two stated above.
- **Good**:
  Provide comment on both best practices and OP's method. This also includes asking clarifying questions. "Is the question for self-study or homework?", "Why are you choosing this approach over better options?", etc...
- **Bail**: If none of the conditions are met, especially the first two, downvote the question, and move on. If OP does not respond to requests to improve the quality of the question, the reason for the approach, and clarity on output, VTC, and move on.

Comment: [I'm following your guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36905732/4497050), but I'm not always sure where the line is between merely inefficient and tragically misguided.

Answer (score 12):

Okay, so there exist questions about how to best shoot oneself in the foot. But do they actually make the sites less useful?

I believe the contrary. If people want to know how to do (bad practice) X, they should find the answer is "First, don't. It doesn't work because of Y. If you really want to do X, then at least mitigate the harm by doing Z". This is a better situation than *not* finding the answer at all.

If nobody posts such answer, the solution is to post it yourself rather than remove the question.

Answer (score 10):

This is something that there is no general case solution to.  It's something that each person will need to make an individualized decision about based on the specific context.  Here are some factors to consider though:

Is the bad practice universally inferior to another approach, or just often worse?  For example, a given solution might be more powerful, but harder to do correctly, easier to mess up, etc.  Such solutions are things to avoid where possible, but it's not always possible.  In such a situation you might want to get more information out of the question to determine if that situation truly calls for the more dangerous solution.

How problematic is the "problematic" solution?  If this really is an inappropriate application, or if the solution is implemented poorly, are we talking about the code running 10% slower because the solution is just strictly less efficient, or a major security vulnerability that could easily allow malicious users to steal sensitive information?  For the former I'd encourage the OP to use the better solution, but if they really insist, it's not like it's *that* harmful for them to be given the improper solution; here is a case where it's probably okay to post an answer with the solution that they specifically asked for, but to include in the answer why it might not be the best solution, and to also mention how you feel the problem *should* be solved.  For the more serious problems it may well be actively harmful to even include the specific solution asked for at all; you're probably best explaining why such a solution is entirely unacceptable under any circumstances, and including an appropriate solution.  If the OP doesn't like such an answer, that's on them.  In these more serious cases you may feel strongly enough to downvote another answer providing such a dangerous solution.  Of course, where you draw the line between "not a good idea, but usually not too dangerous" and "unacceptably harmful" is going to vary between people, technologies, and other aspects of the context of the question.

Comment: Typically the problematic solutions show up in answers, not questions, but I agree with your first sentence wholeheartedly. A question revealing an approach that would cause a major security vulnerability is actually a good thing, because others will almost certainly have the same question and we have an opportunity to offer a correction via answer and possibly save some person their job. I could see someone insisting on the insecure option when setting up an intentionally insecure system... maybe for testing a home-grown vulnerability detection tool or some such craziness.

Answer (score 8):

Special requirements (for instance: I cannot use X, that won't work) are allowed but must be stated in the question itself. A question where they aren't should either be edited to include them or put on hold until edited by OP to include them.

The goal here is not to waste the time of contributors and future readers alike. People willing to answer cannot be required to dig through all the comments on all the previous answers to find out certain limitations that OP didn't mention himself.

Future readers cannot be expected to do the same either. And a future reader that reads such a question seeking guidance could be forgiven to think the bad but specifically required method is the go-to way for such a problem, if there is an accepted answer advocating it. That is a highly undesireable scenario, so it is important that special requirements are stated in the question itself.

Comment: If we are speaking in generalities, though, "bad methods" are very subjective. An approach you despise may be adulated by another, and vice versa.

Comment: @JDB I think this focuses more on "obviously bad in any other context" approaches. Like my question that ends in me using `longjmp()` to break a loop :p

Comment: Understood, but that line is pretty fuzzy. Something that may look obviously bad may actually be acceptable on closer inspection. For example, a question about parsing HTML with regex may look bad, until you read more carefully and realize that the question is about search and replace in a well-known document. Many users are novices (which is why SO exists), and sometimes the terminology gets mangled. You really need to take each question on its own rather than trying to come up with a universal rule.

Comment: @JDB Thats why special requirements should always be in the question. If something is generally not bad practice, it still doesn't hurt to have them in there. If something _is_, having them in there is vital.

Comment: If the OP is aware that the approach is not recommended, then I agree that putting that in the question can head off a lot of confusion. However, addressing surrounding circumstances is generally recommended for *all* questions. There are plenty of XY questions that seem to adhere to best practices, but are asking about totally the wrong thing. The point is that the lines around what's "best" practice and what's a "special" requirement are very fuzzy and change with time. Take each question as it comes and don't paint with too wide a brush.

Answer (score 0):

It often freaks me out when I need to do something, I google it and I find a question where somebody wanted the same thing for different (wrong?) reasons and SO community stumped him into ground and forced their "correct answer" on him.

I always leave a snarky comment as an addition to the downvote at those posts (the "correct" answers) and I wonder - should I ask a duplicate of this question because the "right" answer only fits OP's specific case?

I'm not sure what's wrong with you guys. If you warn OP and he insists, either provide desired answer or just don't answer. This is how I answer such questions:

> Well first, doing this might be a bad idea because [... security blah blah ...]. Now with that out of the way:
>
> #### The dirty solution
>
> The answer to the question is this dirty:
>
> ```
> /** Cast away const or something here **/
> ```

Comment: I totally agree.  Far too many Purists on SO.  Sometimes, a slightly sub-optimal method can be much friendlier or time-saving.

Comment: Slightly sub-optimal, yes. Sometimes, an unexperienced programmer will ask the wrong question because their perspective is uninformed. When [I answer those kind of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101933/how-can-i-use-a-string-to-access-a-perl-array-element/2102314#2102314), I try to first warn about the effects of having rope tied around your neck, and then tell them where to get a longer rope or how to build the stool they ask for.